# How does the exp work?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

Recently I have been trying to increase my team's power and noticed that I level up much faster when playing the later levels than when I play the early ones. I know that in pokemon it gets harder to level up because of the exp increase from level to level, but in *Fire Emblem: Awakening* each level only requires 100 exp. So what determines how much exp you get from an enemy?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/117370/20456

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The experience gain is based on several factors. If you hit an enemy, you obviously gain some experience. If you defeat them, you gain significantly more. The amount of experience these actions give you are based on **your character's level in relation to the enemy unit's level.**

A level 1 promoted unit is essentially a level 21, if that helps these make sense.

This question has been asked many times on GameFAQs, and I find [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/468480-fire-emblem/56968653) to be particularly helpful and informative.

Comment: Why don't you summarize the information from the linked thread?  That ensures the information is here in your answer, in case that thread ever gets removed.

Comment: I answered his question. The information in that thread is general fire emblem, not necessarily specific to awakening. It's a helpful resource, but doesn't necessarily provide an answer. I can remove the link if you think it wise.